# Cardinal numbers - separation of words with a space beyond 100 000

Tags: grammar, numbers

I have stumbled upon this link on the web: http://www.languagesandnumbers.com/how-to-count-in-italian/en/ita/.
I states: "*Numbers are grouped in words of three digits, with the specific rule that **a space is added after the word for thousand if its multiplier is greater than one hundred and does not end with a double zero** (e.g.: duemilatrecentoquarantacinque [2,345], seicentomiladue [600,002], settecentosessantacinquemila duecento [765,200]).*"
I cannot find any confirmation in any Italian source. Moreover, in some reports of Italian authorities, I always see such complex numbers written as a single word, regardless of the "double zero" presence.
So, is this rule a nonsense?

Comment: I never heard of it, and I don't trust too much that web page (for instance, *biliardo* is “billiards”, the game, not 10^15), but you never know.

Comment: I had half an idea that we already covered something similar: [here it is](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/is-novecentonovantanovemilanovecentonovantanove-one-word). More importantly, [in a page of the Treccani website](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/numerali-prontuario_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) you can find a counterexample to that alleged rule: *seicentocinquantaquattromilatrecentoventuno* for 654,321.

Comment: @DaG See http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/biliardo_%28Enciclopedia-della-Matematica%29/ for “biliardo”. Apart from that strange and wrong rule on adding a space, the page seems fully correct to me.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I just find it strange that this word only appears in the Enciclopedia della matematica and in no other reference work, either by Treccani or other publishers (and I used to be a mathematician, so this is not some sort of prejudice).

Comment: @DaG I find it strange too. Personally I prefer American style “small scale”.

Answer (score 5):

I have never heard that rule. In Italy we learn to read and write numbers this way:

**Reading and writing 3 digits numbers:**
100  = cento. It is an exception to the rule, you read “cento”, not “unocento”.
**2**00 = **due**cento
**3**00 = **tre**cento
**4**00 = **quattro**cento
**4**30 = **quattro**centotrenta
**4**32 = **quattro**centotrentadue
**7**07 = **sette**centosette

> **RULE:**
>   **if, after thousands, you have a 80 number, you have to delete one “o”:**
>   180 = centottanta (not: centoottanta)
>   287 = duecentottantasette (not: duecentoottantasette)
>   **if, after thousands, you have number 8, you have to leave the double “o”**
>   708 = settecent**oo**tto
>   808 = ottocent**oo**tto

**Reading and writing 4 digits numbers:**

> **fist of all, in Italy we write 1.000 with a dot to group thousands, not comma.**
>   **Comma is used as “decimal point”, which separates decimal numbers from the whole number.**
>   A number in standard form is separated into groups of three digits:
>   1.000
>   10.000
>   100.000
>   1.000.000

To read them, 1.000 is an exception to the rule, you read “mille”, not “unomila”
**2**.000 = **due**mila
**3**.000 = **tre**mila
**10**.000 = **dieci**mila
**15**.000 = **quindici**mila
**100**.000 = **cento**mila
**107**.311 = **centosette**milatrecentoundici
765.200 = settecentosessantacinquemiladuecento (your example)

**RULE TO READ:**

- you read the number at the left of the dot
- you read the dot as “mila”;
- you read the digits at the right of the dot. If you have only “zero” digits, you have to stop:

10.000 = diecimila (“10” = dieci + “.” = mila “000” = nothing to write or read)
199.000 = centonovantanovemila
199.007 = centonovantanovemilasette

**Reading and writing 6 digits numbers:**
1.000.000 = un milione
1.001.001 = un milione e milleuno

**Reading and writing 10 digits numbers:**
1.001.001.001 = un miliardo, un milione e milleuno

507.935.399.011 = cinquecentosettemiliardi, novecentotrentacinque milioni, trecentonovantanovemila e undici

507.935.888.333 = cinquecentosettemiliardi, novecentotrentacinque milioni, ottocentottantottomila e trecentotrentatré

**Reading and writing 13 digits numbers:**

1.000.000.000.000 = un bilione
(= mille miliardi)

1.001.001.001.001 = un bilione, un miliardo, un milione e milleuno

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. It might be worth mentioning that sometimes one might also see an _apostrophe_ (') used as a symbol to group thousands, especially in scholastic contexts.

Comment: @Easymode44 the apostrophe is only used in Swiss italian (e.g.: http://www.caffe.ch/stories/economia/62634_la_badante__un_lusso_4mila_franchi_al_mese/). In Italy a high dot is sometime used instead of the normal one, mainly in handwriting (I guess there's a specific Unicode character for it, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Yes, I know they use apostrophe in Switzerland, but only for currencies and coordinates, for other units of measurement they use comma. In Italy I have never seen that.

Comment: The apostrophe is never used as a separator, just the dot. Some publishers, however, shun the dot and prefer a half-space.

Comment: Personally, even though they are defined in the vocabularies, I'd avoid _bilione_ (and its cousin _trilione_), since in my experience only misunderstanding and confusion come from them.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed by the comments! I myself going to school in Rome have been taught (at least up until high school) to use apostrophes when separating groups of thousands. I might have had a quaint (or Swiss) teacher, I guess, nevertheless good point @OldManofAran, it is mainly in handwriting that one sees this.